# One to One mapping in same table

Tags: java, spring, database, hibernate, jpa

I want to create columns of class B which is present inside class A as a field in same table as class A, where B has One to One relationship with A.
For example,

```
@Entity
public class A{
   String str;
   boolean flag;

   @OneToOne
   B b;
}
```

```
@Entity
public class B{
  String str2;
  int a;
}
```

I want the table to look like this,

```
 Column | Type
        |
 str    | character
 flag   | boolean
 str2   | character
 a      | integer
```

How can I do this.

Comment: Does class B really need to be an entity in its own right?  Are you sure it wouldn't do simply to [embed](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-embedded-embeddable) an instance in A?

Comment: Yes may be it is better to embed in A. But I am also curious now to know how to do this specific thing.

Comment: You probably *can't* do that specific thing.  JPA persistence providers generally assume that non-polymorphic entities have their own tables.  I don't think the JPA spec requires that explicitly, but it, too, seems to take that as an implicit assumption.

Comment: More generally, there are two viable approaches to designing an ORM persistence model.  You can start with the classes and fit a database to them, or you can start with the database and fit classes to it.  If you try to specify design requirements on both sides at the same time, however, then you can wind up unable to fulfill them all.

Comment: If B doesn't have its own identity, it isn't an entity but an embeddable. Embeddables can live in their own or the owning entities Table, while Entities must be be able to exist on their own (which your B's cannot).